# Issue with freetype2 by installing polybar on arch

Tags: arch-linux

when I try to install polybar on Arch (with AUR, or without), I always get an error with header's include of freetype2, because he's seeking freetype and not freetype2.
I tried to correct the issue by changing all the freetype by freetype2 (without success...)
Here's the log of polybar install : https://hastebin.com/oxerutises.coffeescript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

The issue seems to be that `xproto.pc` cannot be found. Arch recently did some cleanup related to xorg packages which changed some of the dependencies around the `xorgproto` package. Polybar relied on `xorgproto` without knowing it, and with these changes that dependency was no longer satisfied because polybar did not make it explicit.

I have now updated the AUR packages to include `xorgproto` as a compile-time dependency to polybar. Please redownload the `PKGBUILD` and try to build again.